# juego netbeans java

Tags: java

El problema es el siguiente:

> Debo hacer un juego en donde hay 2 jugadores. La idea del juego es
>   que el primer jugador oprime un carácter y el segundo jugador oprime
>   el mismo carácter del jugador 1, y aparte oprime uno mas, y el jugador
>   uno oprime la misma secuencia del jugador 2 mas uno adicional.

**Ejemplo**:

> jugador 1 oprime letra "a" jugador 2 oprime letra "a" y la "m" jugador
>   1 debe seguir la secuencia de letras y adicionar una "am" y "j"

*pierde el que rompa la secuencia...*

En la variable `posicion` guardo la secuencia menos la ultima letra para comparar si es igual a la digitada anteriormente.

Les agradezco sugerencias, el programa se queda en bucle pidiendo letras y no compara las cadenas. Gracias

```
       public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    String nombre;
    String nombre_2;
    String secuencia_1;
    String secuencia_2;
    String contador_secuencia = "";
    boolean continua_juego = true;
    String posicion = "";

    System.out.println("nombre 1");
    nombre = teclado.next();
    System.out.println("nombre 2");
    nombre_2  = teclado.next();

    do {
     System.out.println(nombre + "Digite letra");
     secuencia_1 = teclado.next();
     contador_secuencia += secuencia_1;
     System.out.println(nombre_2 + "Digite letra 2");
     secuencia_2 = teclado.next();

    for (int i =1; i<secuencia_2.lenght();i++) {

    posicion = secuencia_2.substring(0, contador_secuencia.lenght()-1);                             
     if (contador_secuencia_1.equals(posicion)) 
     continua_juego = true;
   else
    continua_juego = false;

  } while (continua_juego = true);
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

!Buenas!

Te lo he resuelto a mi manera, ya que habrá mil formas de hacerlo...

Es un juego sencillo pero puede ser lioso al principio. Lo he realizado con varios `if` y `else`. Creo que a primera vista se entiende el código, pero igual forma te explico algunas partes que no se puedan ver claras.

**Código completo** (Lo he realizado todo en la clase `main` como lo tienes):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Juego {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nombre1, nombre2;
    String secuenciaJugador;
    boolean continuar = true;
    String secuencias = "";

    System.out.print("Introduce tu nombre jugador 1: ");
    nombre1 = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Introduce tu nombre jugador 2: ");
    nombre2 = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\n" + nombre1 + " introduce la secuencia inicial: ");
    secuenciaJugador = sc.nextLine();

    secuencias = secuencias + secuenciaJugador;

    do {

        System.out.print(nombre2 + " adivina la secuencia: ");
        secuenciaJugador = sc.nextLine();

        if(secuenciaJugador.equalsIgnoreCase(secuencias)) {

            continuar = true;

            System.out.print(nombre2 + " introduce la nueva secuencia: ");
            secuenciaJugador = sc.nextLine();

            secuencias = secuencias + secuenciaJugador;


            System.out.print(nombre1 + " adivina nueva secuencia: ");
            secuenciaJugador = sc.nextLine();

            if(secuenciaJugador.equalsIgnoreCase(secuencias)) {

                System.out.print(nombre1 + " introduce la nueva secuencia: ");
                secuenciaJugador = sc.nextLine();

                secuencias = secuencias + secuenciaJugador;

            }else {

                System.out.println("SE ACABA EL JUEGO");
                continuar = false;
            }

        }else {

            System.out.println("SE ACABA EL JUEGO");
            continuar = false;
        }


    }while(continuar);

    sc.close();

}
```

}

El **porque** de tanto `if` y `else` es para ir cambiando la pregunta que se le hace al usuario que esta jugando. Para que se aprecie cuando se debe de adivinar la secuencia y cuando insertar una nueva secuencia.

Justo debajo de todo texto donde incluya un "nueva secuencia" he añadido la nueva letra a lo que seria el "contador" o "total" de secuencias:

```
secuencias = secuencias + secuenciaJugador;
```

Solo he colocado una variable donde recoger el valor introducido por el usuario para ahorrar variables, y así ir sobrescribiendo la que tenemos.

Creo que debes de entender bien la lógica del ejercicio, y para mejorarlo un poco puedes cambiar los tipo `String` por `char` por ejemplo, pero eso a tu elección...

Si te surge alguna duda escribe un comentario y edito :)

**EDITO**

El juego avanza de esta forma. El primer jugador empieza indicando un carácter que sera la primera secuencia. Después, se le dice al jugador 2 que acierte la secuencia, **y si lo hace**, el debe de de indicar un nuevo carácter... Y así en bucle hasta que alguno de los dos falle.

```
Introduce tu nombre jugador 1: dani
Introduce tu nombre jugador 2: pepe

dani introduce la secuencia inicial: a
pepe adivina la secuencia: a
pepe introduce la nueva secuencia: b
dani adivina nueva secuencia: ab
dani introduce la nueva secuencia: c
pepe adivina la secuencia: abc
pepe introduce la nueva secuencia: f
dani adivina nueva secuencia: abcf
dani introduce la nueva secuencia:
```

Tienes que comprender mejor el código, y lo que estas pidiendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudas a entender mejor;sin embargo no debe ingresar nueva cadena sino comparar la que ya existe y colocar un valor adicional.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, es lo que hace el programa. Funciona de la siguiente manera: El Jugador 1 inicia la secuencia, después, el Jugador 2 debe de acertar la secuencia y si acierta, introduce un nuevo valor adicional, después, pasa a Jugador 1 y hace lo mismo. En el momento que alguno de los dos, falle, se acaba el juego. ¿Te refieres a eso?

Comment: Creo no me hago entender, el juego debe ser todo basado en la misma cadena, sin introducir una nueva cadena, es un juego de memoria, como cuando de pequeños nos decian una fruta y el siguiente otra y otra y asi hasta que alguien se equivocara en el orden de la secuencia.

Comment: Si pruebas y ves el código, veras que no se crea una nueva secuencia. Siempre es la misma y cada jugador añade un nuevo carácter hasta que uno de los dos falle.

Comment: al correr el juego se acaba en el segundo turno

Comment: No termina en el segundo turno. Te edito la respuesta y te copio un ejemplo de como voy jugando.

Comment: dani introduce la secuencia inicial: a
pepe adivina la secuencia: a
pepe introduce la nueva secuencia: ab
dani adivina nueva secuencia: ab
dani introduce la nueva secuencia: abc
pepe adivina la secuencia: abc
pepe introduce la nueva secuencia: abcf
dani adivina nueva secuencia: abcf
dani introduce la nueva secuencia:abcdfm   .Si, ya comprendo la estructura, sin embargo esta lògica debo implementarla en android, por lo tanto necesitaria que al introducir la nueva secuencia introdujera todo lo que lleva mas el nuevo caracter. Como lo coloque arriba, asì tendrìa que poder ejecutarlo

Comment: Con el código que he realizado creo que tendrás suficiente para implementar un par de cambios en él (que es lo que necesita para adaptarlo a tu proyecto). Te invito a que intentes realizarlo y así puedas aprender tu mismo. En mi planteamiento, se pide un un nuevo patron con una pregunta diferente, y tu quieres escribir todo en la misma linea. Dale una vuelta, y tomatelo como aprendizaje. En caso de no saber hacerlo después de todo, vuelve, y te ayudo encantado. Un saludo, y suerte.